# encoding url using swift code

Tags: ios, swift, url, nsurl

I need to send an URL in Arabic language, so I need to encode it before I put it in URL. I am using Swift code.

Below is an example what i really need

```
var s = "www.example.com/السلام عليكم"

let url = NSURL(string : s)
```

So the word (السلام عليكم) is in Arabic characters that what I want to send.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28734595/2303865

Answer (score 35):

**Swift 2.0**

```
let urlwithPercentEscapes = myurlstring.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

**Swift 3**

```
let urlwithPercentEscapes = myurlstring.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Comment: Swift 3 should be: let urlwithPercentEscapes = myurlstring.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed ) without parentheses after NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed because it is a property not a function.

Comment: https://abc.world.com/i/johnhans/MA_Cover_ABCTan_MB_djnfkddfgdgd_v.43-44?layer1=[text=INCOMING:&fontSize=76&textColor=#ffffff&textAlign=center&anchor=MC&left=50%&top=42%]&layer2=[text=Winter%20days&fontSize=164&textColor=#ffffff&textAlign=center&anchor=MC&left=50%&top=50%]&

I tried to encode this in swift but when i pass it to URL. It always return nil

How can i encode it

Answer (score 11):

To improve [@Druva's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38154976/1979882)
create an extention somewhere in the project

**Swift 2.0**

```
extension String
{   
    func encodeUrl() -> String
    {
        return self.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
    }
func decodeUrl() -> String
    {
        return self.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
    }

}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
 extension String
    {   
        func encodeUrl() -> String
        {
            return self.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        }
    func decodeUrl() -> String
        {
            return self.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to encode url as you have written. You can do so with that string method:

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSStringEncoding)
```

So your code will be:

```
var s = "www.example.com/السلام عليكم"
// you may add check before force unwrapping
let url = NSURL(string : s.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to encode this string as it contains special characters.

```
var s = "www.example.com/السلام عليكم"
let encodedLink = s.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)
let encodedURL = NSURL(string: encodedLink!)! as URL
```

where encodedURL is your final URL

Comment: Do not use `NSURL` in Swift. Use `URL`.

Answer (score 1):

**swift 4**
we face the same problem it solved by this way

```
extension String { 
var fixedArabicURL: String?  {
       return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.alphanumerics
           .union(CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed)
           .union(CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed))
   } }
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to Encode this URL before sending this URL